# Real time TCP server in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, tcp

I have a TCP server in Node.JS. When I get to more than a 1000 packets per second suddenly everything is delayed.

Not just a short delay, but a 3-4 second delay. Which is very bad for my realtime server.

So, why is this happening? I have used `process.nextTick` on receiving and sending packets but I still have the problem.

Possible design problem:

This tries to broadcast packets to all relevant players in the area. Might be that the loop is hogging the processing?

```
        // TO BE REFACTORED
        var listOffset = packet.readUInt16LE(6); // the users to broadcast to
        var listSize   = packet.readUInt8(listOffset);
        var payload    = packet.slice(10, listOffset); 
        // broadcast
        while (listSize--) {
          var userNo = packet.readUInt16LE(listOffset + 1 + (listSize * 2));
          var client = Server.getConnection(userNo);
          if (client) client.send(payload);
        }
```

Relevant functions:

```
getConnection is this._connections[id]
client.send is this._socket.write(data)
```

Comment: If it takes more than 1 ms to process a single packet, then your server can't keep up with 1000 packets per second.   Could that be the issue?

Comment: @jfriend00 possibly, considering node.js isn't made for computing, packets are decrypted or encrypted (native addon) upon arrival or exit, a few checksums are done. Few more checking per packet which could sum upto 1 ms or more. So I guess `node.js` can't handle this kind of use-case?

Comment: It's far too early to say this is a problem particular to node.js.  It depends entirely upon your code and what you're doing with these packets.  You haven't included any of the relevant code so we can't comment on that.  If I was tasked with building the highest scale packet router possible and speed/scalability was the ultimate goal, I would probably build it in C/C++ with perhaps some sections of code even in hand crafted assembly so you do have to pick the tool that is right for the job.  On the other hand, it is also quite possible that what your code is doing can be improved in node.js.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is for a MMORPG server. I think the bottleneck happens when there are thousands of players and monsters that are all in the area of interest and all movements of monsters have to be broadcasted to all players in that area. I'll add the relevant code.

Comment: Your loop would prevent any processing of incoming packets until the loop was done since node is single threaded.  You could output both the `listSize` and the total duration of time to execute the whole loop to a log to see if that is indeed where your delay is coming from.  You don't show the code for `getConnection()` or `client.send()` either so those are other areas of interest if they are inefficient.  In particular `getConnection()` could be an `o(n)` operation if not done efficiently.

Comment: You also may need to prioritize processing of some types of activity to be done first before other types of activity.   For example, broadcasting new locations of monsters might be a lower priority activity and you get behind in that, you might have to skip broadcasting some intermediate positions so you can process other more important things in order to catch up.

Comment: @jfriend00 updated my question, yeah, i guess that would be a better approach. Anyway how do you do priorities in node? Should I implement a scheduler and pass all processing there? make the scheduler do the prioritization? instead of sending directly?

Comment: There are many approaches for prioritizing mini-tasks, but most would create one or more queues of work and process a smallish chunk of work and then look in the queues again to see what you should do next based on pending tasks and priorities.  The main issue you want to solve here is that broadcast updates may need to be lowest priority and may need to be coalesced so if you get behind in processing you replace an older position with a newer position and only send the most recent position.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see whether the event loop is blocked or something else is going on (e.g. garbage collection or I don't know what), you might measure the event loop time. Simply start setImmediate() now and then and measure the time it takes to execute the callback using process.hrtime(). If the event loop is blocked for a long time, you will see it coming up using this method. 
If you see cycle times below 10ms, the loop is not the problem and you need to search for something else.